# How to calculate count of enties by common columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database I have 2 table (*ALPHA* and *BETA*). I am tring to make SQL request which will join new column to ALPHA table. In that new column (`INFO_COUNT`) I need to store count of entries by `INFO_ID` field. I need some advice how to make it.

**Table 'ALPHA'**:

```
       TIME_KEY      | INFO_ID | STATUS
---------------------|---------|---------
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 1       | Green
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 2       | Red
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 3       | Red
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 4       | Green
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 5       | Green
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 6       | Green
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 7       | Red
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 8       | Green
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 9       | Green
```

**TABLE 'BETA'**:

```
INFO_ID | LOCATION |
--------|----------|
1       | USA      |
5       | India    |
5       | India    |
8       | China    |
9       | Canada   |
9       | Canada   |
```

I want such result:

```
       TIME_KEY      | INFO_ID | STATUS | INFO_COUNT
---------------------|---------|--------|------------
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 1       | Green  | 1
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 2       | Red    | NULL
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 3       | Red    | NULL
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 4       | Green  | NULL
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 5       | Green  | 2
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 6       | Green  | NULL
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 7       | Red    | NULL
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 8       | Green  | 1
 2018-04-08 10:00:00 | 9       | Green  | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `left join` and aggregation.  Here is one way:

```
select a.*, b.info_count
from alpha a left join
     (select b.info_id, count(*) as info_count
      from b
      group by b.info_id
     ) b
     on a.info_id = b.info_id;
```